# Why does validation fail in code, but work in Newtonsoft web validator?

Tags: json.net, jsonschema

This should validate against the schema as verified in the online Newtonsoft validator at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ The schema looks correct (although siblings to $ref are not technically valid in JSON Schema 7.)  Instead I get a validation error.  To repro:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema;
using System.Net;

namespace TestValidation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new WebClient();
            var schema = JSchema.Parse(client.DownloadString("https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=B22A8A90BE24B544&resid=B22A8A90BE24B544%211131778&authkey=AMRvXjC2uXSPy3s"));
            var file = JObject.Parse(client.DownloadString("https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=B22A8A90BE24B544&resid=B22A8A90BE24B544%211131779&authkey=AAwVQjelPWA7HZ4"));
            file.Validate(schema);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Siblings of `$ref` MUST be ignored before draft `2019-09` according to draft 7 and 2019-09 specification documents. Pleas include your actual schema and actual instance data in your question. Links die, and then your question becomes useless to anyone else reading it.

Comment: The files are way to big to include in this post--click on them and they are there.  (And this is the stack overflow recommendation for big files.)  The Newtonsoft schema validator happily validates instances of all of the other $ref with siblings and also validates in the online version.  I understand siblings are not supported by JSON Schema draft 7 and will eventually be able to move to 2019-09, but the tool chain is still too immature on that.